# How to parse a csv string and convert into a Hash

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV string or you can assume the body of a csv file. I want to find a particular record in that file(CSV STRING) and delete all the records before it.
Then convert the remaining records into a hash. ie the header as the key and the row content  as the value.
At any moment you cannot create a new file.

Comment: And what have you done yourself? What did you try, and what problems did you run into?

Comment: I had the CSV string . Then I did CSV.readlines which converted it into array of arrays. I found the index of that record and took all the records after that. But then entire record becomes a string to separate the values I used split(",") but it also seperated the values which had string for example it had a value 23,56 it seperated it as 23 and 56 and gave 2 different elements

Comment: Please post code, show what worked, and where you have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSV library.

For Ruby 1.9 it is already [builtin](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html). With Ruby 1.8, you can either use the included CSV library or [fastercsv](http://rubygems.org/gems/fastercsv) which is the basis for the implementation built into 1.9.

---

P.S. When asking question is is generally requested that you provide a snipped of code where you have problems, exactly define your issue, i.e. what you expect to see and what you are actually seeing and show that you have thought about how you could solve the problem yourself before. That way, people are much more willing to answer to your problems as it shows your respect to the respondents and helps future visitors with a similar problem to better understaand the problem and deduct a solution applicable to them.